# Detecting click on radio button + label:before

Tags: jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I'll start by admitting that HTML and JavaScript are not my forte.

That, however, didn't deter me from creating this: http://jsfiddle.net/asarkar/wuXrE/.

Problem is, I need to detect the click on the radio buttons and change the text box and buttons texts accordingly.

I've come to realize that `before` elements are not part of the DOM so clicks on them can't be detected. So am I dead in the water here?

Using `requireJS 2.1.11` and `jQuery 2.1.0`.

Comment: You can use `.prev()` in jQuery to find the [previous element](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: Also, what do you want to change on click? Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/wuXrE/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/wuXrE/5/

Comment: @tewathia Please post your solution as an answer so that I can accept it.
Also, see my follow up question to 'adeneo'.

Comment: @Luxelin I didn't follow. Why would I find a previous element? All I'm trying to do is detect which radio button to click.
To answer your question about what do I want to change, it's the `placeholder` on the text box and the button text. Selecting `get` should show 'URL' and 'Search' while selecting `post` should display 'Directory` and 'Index' respectively. I got that working now.

Comment: I said that in regard to what you said about `before` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `change` event for radio buttons, **not** the `click` event.
The `change` event fires when the radio buttons change, regardless of what changed them, keyboard interaction, clicking the label etc.

Also both radio buttons have ID's, and ID's are generally the fastest selector to look up in the DOM, and is much preferred over non standard psuedo selectors.

```
$('#get, #post').on('change', function() {

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wuXrE/2/)

Comment: Thank you, it works. I like @tewathia answer a little better because it requires less typing, otherwise both answers are equivalent.
On a slightly separate note, is there a way to increase the size of the "white dot" that indicates a radio button is checked?